# Mocking Cake Request

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, mocking, phpunit

I am developing a test for a controller function and basically it just acts upon a cake request, is there anyway to mock cake request inside the test function so that whenever the controller tries to access $this->request->data it returns the data i have set in the test case? if there is a way please tell me how.

Regards

Comment: Have you heard of PHPUnit? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html

Comment: Yes, actually i mocked the Auth component to be able to return the user whenever my controller asks for it, not sure how to do it with cake request tho
    $this->myController= $this->generate('Posts', array(
    'components' => array('Session','Auth' => array('User'), ) ));

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-controllers) contains an example of how to set the request data.  For quick reference:

```
public function testIndexPostData() {
    $data = array(
        'Article' => array(
            'user_id' => 1,
            'published' => 1,
            'slug' => 'new-article',
            'title' => 'New Article',
            'body' => 'New Body'
        )
    );
    $result = $this->testAction(
        '/articles/index',
        array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post')
    );
    debug($result);
}
```